# Countdown using handler.postDelayed not working

Tags: java, android

It seems that postDelayed is not waiting.  I'm running this inside a Fragment.

```
// count down
mCounterTextView.setText(Integer.toString(sCountDownFrom));
final Handler handler = new Handler();
for(int i = (sCountDownFrom-1); i >= 0; i--) {
    final int index = i;
    Log.d("ZoneHelp", "countdown: " + Integer.toString(index));
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do this after the delay
            mCounterTextView.setText(Integer.toString(index));
        }
    }, 1000); // 1 second counter
}
```

when I run this it the three logs (2,1,0) print out immediately and I don't get the affect I'm hoping for.

Comment: try after making delay dynamic for all Handler's like 1000,1000+500,1500+500,... to see textview update

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself with this code... thank you for the comment.  I realized what was happening because of it.  Here is my solution:

```
class CountRunnable implements Runnable {
  private final int mCount;

  public CountRunnable(final int count) {
    mCount = count;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    mCounterTextView.setText(Integer.toString(mCount));
  }
}

// count down
mCounterTextView.setText(Integer.toString(sCountDownFrom));
final Handler handler = new Handler();
for(int i = (sCountDownFrom-1), j=0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
  Log.d("ZoneHelp", "countdown: " + Integer.toString(i));
  handler.postDelayed(new CountRunnable(i), 500+(j*1000)); // 1 second counter
}
```